# NextGEN Gallery: Use the same galleries on 2 or more sites on WP network (multisite)?

Tags: multisite, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I have a wordpress network with 4 sites and i use NextGEN Gallery V1.9.13.

On the 2 sites (first and second on network) i use the same galleries. It is a bit waste of hosting space if I need to upload the same images on the 2 network sites.

Is there a possibility to use the gallery of first net site with the second net site?

I tried copy the ngg_options of wp_option(first site of network) to ngg_options of wp_2_option but it doesn't read the base of the first site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow the steps of this [tutorial](http://zoomladesign.com/2010/03/import-database-tables-nextgen-plugin-new-domain/) , on step 3 the only extra that you have to do is to replace all the base prefix from your site that whant to use the same gallery with the new one. If the main site is "wp_" and the subdomain that you want to use the same photos is wp_2yo u have to change on step 3 too.

Also,

**TAKE CARE NOT TO DESTROY YOUR WHOLE WORDPRESS INSTALLATION!**

1.look for the "wp_options"-table

2.edit the row "ngg_options"

3.in field "option_value" look for something like "gallerypath";s:31:"wp-content/blogs.dir/%BLOG_ID%/files/"
and change it to
"gallerypath";s:31:"wp-content/blogs.dir/galleries/"
(or whatever you like your galleries-folder to be)

look for more tables like "wp_**_options" (where ** is the number of your blog, may be several depending of the amount of blog u set up), repeat step 2 + 3 for every wp_option table u find